# PHP errors : No display & No log

Tags: php, apache, symfony, logging, php-5.4

I checked which `php.ini` is used with `phpinfo()`, so **I'm editing the right php config file**.

In that `php.ini` file (and in `phpinfo()` details) I have `display_errors` at `On` and `error_reporting` at `E_ALL`.

BUT when I have a PHP error, most of the time I find **no log** (in the file specified by `error_log`, nor in the file specified in apache vhost, nor in `/var/syslog`), and only a **blank page displayed**.
I also tried to use the `ini_set("display_errors", 1)` but that didn't change anything.

One thing was weird, I had no `php5` folder in `/var/log` (I created it, and configured `error_log` to use it).

Any idea would be much appreciated, that's not so great to code without knowing anything about the errors you have !

*P.S. I'm using PHP 5.4 & Symfony2 (using the `app_dev.php` file), on Debian Wheezy.*

***Edit : Error logs now work thanks to @martinezjc , but still having a blank page in Apache.***

Comment: do php errors log to your specified error log if they are generated outside of a symfony2 application?  I don't have symphony experience, but I wonder if the framework is handling the errors for you and logging them somewhere within the application.  Just a guess though

Comment: Actually only Symfony2 errors are displayed/logged. Like options missing, wrong route, etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom directory, remember to assign apache permission

```
mkdir /var/log/php-5-4
chown www-data /var/log/php-5-4
```

The in the php.ini file

```
error_log = /var/log/php-5-4/php_errors.log
```

This link talk about more about logs, you can check it http://doc.exyks.org/wiki/Server_php_log_configuration

Comment: Thank you, that worked for the logs, I forgot to change the permissions apparently.
But what about displaying these errors instead of having a blank page in Apache ?

Comment: you can set in the php.ini file the directive `display_errors = On` or  use directly in your php file `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` :)

Comment: As I said in the original post, I already have `display_errors = On` in my `php.ini`, and I also already tried `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` in my php file.