# parrot linux xampp PHP errors : No display

Tags: php, linux, xampp

My problem is similar to this one [PHP errors : No display & No log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637289/php-errors-no-display-no-log). I've already set display_errors to On in php.ini and tried to add `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` in my php code but it didn't work. Actually it did work for a while but now it doesn't. I can't learn php without displaying errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You can use error_reporting(E_ALL). In case that does not work and you messed up with your .ini file. You can uninstall and reinstall wampp or Xampp.

Comment: it did work but i still got to add `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` in every php code

Comment: I am editing the post. You can have a look at how the ini file should look like. Also attaching the screenshot for error reporting. After editing you ini file you also have to restart the xamp server to apply the changes